# Algorithm to subvidide and calculate balance efficiently

Tags: algorithm, mapreduce, sum, aggregate-functions

Let's say you have a large number of transactions over time flowing into/out of an account.  Every time a new transaction comes in you need to recalculate the balance to show to the user.  It's inefficient to recalculate the total balance (summing up the rows from all transactions) every time a new transaction comes in (imagine there are too many transactions).

Obviously you could increment or decrement the balance.  But lets say actions aren't guaranteed to happen atomically, for example - in between saving a transaction and the increment, your database could restart, missing the increment.

I'm wondering what algorithms/approaches exist to solve this.  It seems like you could:

- do the increment/decrement method, and periodically correct it (it would still show incorrect balance though periodically, not great)
- do a map/reduce, although this is still overkill if new transactions come in frequently (it is going over 100% of old data, even though only  tiny portion changed)
- save some sort of markers over time, so once you sum a period of time once, you can reuse it later, maybe in some sort of hierarchy so you can sum the day's total, week's total, month, year etc so it is always fast to get the current balance (todays transactions plus prior days, weeks, months, years etc)

It seems like this has been invented before.  What should I be searching for?  Thanks!

Comment: *"in between saving ... and the increment, your database could restart"* -- this is what database transactions have been invented for, to do things atomically.

Comment: In all seriousness, the solution to this problem was developed by the accounting and book-keepeing professions over the past 800+ years. It's called double-entry book-keeping with sub-ledgers. The two weeks I spent cramming an introductory and intermediate book-keeping course (with 15 years as a DB developer behind me) provided me nearly as much insight into transactional databases as the previous 15 years.

Comment: An old adage: "If you don't yet undersatnd how it has been done with paper and pencil for 800 years, you do not yet understand it well enough to automate it."

Comment: @NPE you are correct, unfortunately we cannot lock across multiple tables here, it is a limitation of our datastore

Comment: Accumulative sum, Logical Time, Cascading operations, Transaction Control.. think about them

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer Thinking :)

Comment: Here are my suggestions.. 1: You can make two components, one that on-time arrange entries during day-time, the other does batch processing by entry-time-stamps. 2: Keep a field for the amount before the change, or a log .. for that when a transaction's time-stamp is backdating, insert it & accumulate all amounts that comes after.

Comment: Let's say your data set is A+B+C, but you want to fix it now into this: (A+1)+(B-1)+(C*2) = (A+B+C) + FIX ~ FIX = (A+1 -A) + (B-1 -B) + (2C /C)